# Is a “great loss” with regards to Hilchos Shabbos only tangible loss, or also theoretical loss?

Tags: halacha, shabbat

In Hilchos Shabbos there are areas where one can act leniently if not acting as such would cause הפסד מרובה (significant financial loss).

Is such a loss only regarding for tangible “current” or previously invested money, or does it also include a “possible” (I.e theoretical) loss (e.g your money may or may not be in a house that is on fire, etc.)?